# Angular digest loop issue specific example

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, signalr

I've got predictable behaviour of angular digest loop, but have no idea how to solve it in a valid way. So, here it is:
I have a directive, which creates bootstrap datetime picker with a couple of options. This directive has an isolated scope with two-way references ('=OuterScopeValue') to another scope values. The code for the 'post'-part method of the 'compile' is next:

```
post: function(scope, element) {
    var opt = options;
    opt.startDate = scope.startDate;
    opt.endDate = scope.endDate;
    opt.yearsSchedule = [];//scope.years;
    $(element).datetimepicker(opt);
    $(element).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        var fn = function() {
            if (ev.date != null) {
                if (scope.timing == null || scope.timing.valueOf() != ev.date.valueOf()) {
                    var value = (ev.date.valueOf()); // + (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
                    scope.timing = new Date(value).toGMTString();

                }
            } else {
                if (scope.timing != null) {
                    scope.timing = null;
                }
            }
            console.log(ev.date);
        };

        if (scope.$$phase || scope.$root.$$phase) {
            fn();
        } else {
            scope.$apply(fn);
        }
    });

    scope.$watch('disable', function(value) {
        $(element).datetimepicker('reserveEnableOrDisableDates', value, true, false);
    });
    scope.$watch('reserve', function(value) {
        $(element).datetimepicker('reserveEnableOrDisableDates', value, false, true);
    });
    scope.$watch('enable', function (value) {
        $(element).datetimepicker('reserveEnableOrDisableDates', value, false, false);
    });
    scope.$watch('years', function(value) {
        $(element).datetimepicker('updateYears', value);
    });
    scope.$watch('startDate', function(value) {
        $(element).datetimepicker('setStartDate', value);
    });
    scope.$watch('endDate', function(value) {
        $(element).datetimepicker('setEndDate', value);
    });
    scope.$watch('timing', function(value) {
        if (value == null) {
            $(element).datetimepicker('reset');
        }
    });
    scope.$watch('interval', function(value) {
        if (value != null) {
            $(element).datetimepicker('updateInterval', value);
        }
    });
}
```

So what we've got here is a `changeDate` event listener (`changeDate` is always fired by the picker). This event can be fired in two cases: server sent us some date to reserve and this date is our actually chosen date, so we must clear it or we clicked 'X' button of the picker to clear the chosen date. In the first case my data from the server is passed to the controller with broadcasted event (I'm using SignalR and its listeners, which must be specified before the start of the hubs and I'm doing it in the provider's config part so I don't have an access to my controller's scope and must broadcast data I've got from server by the $rootScope service like this in my .config section of the module:

```
var reserveFunction = function (msg) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('reserveEvent', msg);
};
```

then I have a listener in my controller, which calls $apply on my `$scope.scopeReserve` value to start a digest loop and update the picker values:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.scopeReserve = [{ date: new Date(date.valueOf() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000), reserved: false }];
});
```

By the way, the picker starts another loop each time it needs to update its input field. Current solution is to use this antipattern `if (scope.$$phase || scope.$root.$$phase)`, and the problem is: i don't need to call $apply in case when server sends me some data (digest-loop is called from the listener in controller) and I need to start the loop when I clear data manually by pressing 'x' button. So I want to know, how can I fix it or even redesign my application's structure to solve this kind of problem.